# Can not create Communication access tokens for Teams users

Tags: azure

After following [the provided example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-javascript-quickstarts/tree/main/manage-teams-identity-mobile-and-desktop), I'm getting an error:

`The app is trying to access a service (Azure Communication Services) that your organization lacks a service principal for.`

What can cause it?

UPDATE

I tried:

1. Re-create setup following the instruction
2. Create a different service principal with an "Owner" role using

`az ad sp create-for-rbac --name {name} --role Owner --scopes /subscriptions/{id}`

The error is the same

Comment: Could you please provide what you have tried.

Comment: @HariKrishna I followed the instruction on github - nothing else yet

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1030676/oauth-authentication-issue-with-teams-managecalls). The proposed workaround:

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "[Tenant_ID]"  
Install-Module AzureAD # if missing  
New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId "1fd5118e-2576-4263-8130-9503064c837a"
```